# Effective way of transferring data to HLSL shader in MonoGame and storing it

Tags: c#, monogame, hlsl

I'm toying around with HLSL shaders in monogame. Lets say I want to use a structure in my shader which is like this:

```
struct Light
{
    float2 pos;
    float  intensity;
};
```

I'm going to use a varying amount of these Light objects in each frame draw call.

1. In what kind of structure/array should I store my Light objects in my shader? If I understand correctly I can declare an array like this:`Light lights[n];`, however n needs to be known at compile time. I can declare a stupidly large array and fill it with some default initialized garbage that I can check for, however this seems very inefficient.
2. Can I use constant buffers to alleviate my pain? [This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19842/marshalling-c-structs-into-dx11-cbuffers) makes it seem like it would be an efficient way of transferring and using data on the GPU (I have some CUDA experience, so I know about constant memory and such), but I can't wrap my head around how to use them in this case.